# creating futon view and calling the URL by passing parameters in couchDB

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a requirement to create bit complex queries could you please help me to write.

In my data base I have list of docs, for example:

```
{
  "_id": "26",
  "_rev": "1-53ac67e9ec4b4ce8ffa9cd609e107aaf",
  "customer_name": "Praneeth",
  "type": "trip",
  "duration": "10 hours 27 mins",
  "end_time": "Jan 1, 2014 10:11:00 PM",
  "start_time": "Jan 11, 2014 8:46:00 AM",
}
```

Now I want to create a view which can read current `timestamp` and type from the URL to get the docs whose `end_time` is less than or equal to current `timestamp` and type is `"trip"`. Here type could be anything not only the `trip`, based on `type` being passed from the URL I should get the docs.

Suppose if I write in SQL,  query it would be like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE end_time>="current time passed from the URL as key" and type='type passed from the url as key'
```

My view is like below now how to call this view from the URL to get the desired output

```
    function(doc){
var startTime=new Date(doc.start_time);
var endTime=new Date(doc.end_time);
emit([doc.type,endTime.getTime()], doc);
    }
```

is below one is correct??

```
     http://localhost:5984/trip/_design/current_trip/_view/current_trip?startkey=["trip",1388607960000]&end_key={}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `startTime` in your map, so that can be removed. Also `startkey` should be `start_key` in the query string.

Unless you need to be able to dynamically query on the type, you could filter on "trip" in the `map` and not use an array.

```
if(doc.type && doc.type === 'trip') {
    var d = new Date(doc.end_time);
    emit(d, doc);
}
```

You can also partition the dates into an array on year, month, day etc. if you like. E.g. http://danielwertheim.se/2014/05/06/couchdb-partioned-dates-and-group-levels-to-control-aggregation-granularity/

```
if(doc.type && doc.type === 'trip') {
    var d = new Date(doc.end_time);
    emit([d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth() + 1,d.getDate()], doc);
}
```